# Does deleting rows speed up the database performance?

Tags: sqlite

My database had 100k rows and I have deleted 50k rows. The size of the database remains the same after the deletion. My question is, does deleting the rows speed up future query execution despite its same file size?

Comment: Short answer: Somewhat, but not as much as you would get if you vacuumed the database after.

Comment: I'd agree with that, I think I read a post on here a few days ago that someone saw no performance benefit from deleting rows until a vacuum was run - which would match with what the SQLite documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

@David Schwartz wrote:

> Short answer: Somewhat, but not as much as you would get if you vacuumed the database after.

@Kobunite wrote:

> I'd agree with that, I think I read a post on here a few days ago that someone saw no performance benefit from deleting rows until a vacuum was run - which would match with what the SQLite documentation says.

Comment: ([Question answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?rq=1)).